# Google Calendar API suitability

Tags: jakarta-ee, google-calendar-api

I am working on an appointment booking website for my school. Basically I want to be able to make multiple user accounts and have a calendar where you can see the available slots of other teachers/students and book a meeting at an available time, like you would do on Microsoft Outlook Calendar.

After doing a bit of looking around it seemed that people suggested making a calendar was actually fairly complex and suggested Google Calendar API. I've been reading into this a bit and I'm wondering if it is suitable to my project.

I want to have a front end that looks similar to Outlook Calendar and I just need to be able to book appointments and show when appointments are booked. Is Google Calendar API suitable for this or is it over the top? Am I better off just creating this myself? Also will I be able to use the Google calendar UI in my website?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing, *"a front end that looks similar to Outlook Calendar"* and *"able to book appointments and show when appointments are booked"*, is exactly what already exists with Google Calendar and Google Apps for EDU:

[google.com/a/edu](http://google.com/a/edu)

[support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2465776](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2465776)